# How does cin.ignore work with cin and getline?

Tags: c++, input, cin, getline

Here, there are two cins and to my understanding, each one leaves '\n' in the buffer because they skip whitespace.

Cin.ignore only skips one character by default so one of the '\n' is taken out. However, there is still one more '\n' in the buffer, so I would expect the getline to see the '\n' and getline to skip.

However, when I run this code, I am able to type into string3. Where am I going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string string1, string2, string3;
  cout << "String1: ";
  cin >> string1;

  cout << "String2: ";
  cin >> string2; 

  cin.ignore();

  cout << "String3: ";
  getline(cin, string3);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin >> string2` looks for the beginning of the next word, and skips over the newline that was left in the buffer after `cin >> string1`. So at this point ,only the second newline is still in the buffer, and `cin.ignore()` skips past it.

More detailed, if you type:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

The buffer contains:

```
line1\nline2\nline3\n
^
```

The `^` shows the current position in the buffer. At the beginning, it's at the beginning of the buffer. After you do `cin >> string1`, it looks like:

```
line1\nline2\nline3\n
     ^
```

When you do `cin >> string2`, it finds the beginning of the next word (the next `l` character), and after it's done the buffer looks like:

```
line1\nline2\nline3\n
            ^
```

Then `cin.ignore()` skips past the next newline, so it looks like:

```
line1\nline2\nline3\n
              ^
```

And now when you call `getline()`, it reads the line with `line3`.